# Redirect same page but add query string by .htaccess if cookie value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies, mod-rewrite

I have a cookie created to identify the city.

The name of the cookie is this:
`geodefense` that contains the value of the city `Piura`
(This value can change from the cities of my country according to customer)

I need to redirect by adding some query string by `.htaccess` to prevent the page from loading showing prices that are not for the city

For example if I am on the page

```
https://127.0.0.1/myproduct1
```

Redirect only if the `geodefense` cookie exists and **take the value** for the query string

```
https://127.0.0.1/myproduct1?geo=[cookievalue]
```

Currently I have this `.htaccess` code to check if a cookie exists but not how to take the value of the cookie and redirect to the same page but adding the query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I have this `.htaccess` code to check if a cookie exists ...
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value; [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L]
> ```

That code checks that the cookie + specific value does **not** exist (as denoted by the `!` prefix on the *CondPattern*).

However, this would seem to be a bit of an anti-pattern... unnecessarily redirecting the user when the value is already present (and available to your script) in the cookie?! Anyway, to answer your specific question, you would need to do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)geo=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|\s|;)geodefense=(\w+)($|\s|;)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?geo=%1 [QSA,R=302,L]
```

The above redirects any URL that does not already have a `geo` URL parameter *and* the `geodefense` cookie exists with a non-empty value to the same URL, appending the value of the `geodefense` cookie as the value of the `geo` URL-parameter. Any other query string parameters on the original request are then appended (the result of the `QSA` flag).

The first *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) checks that the `geo` URL parameter does not already exist on the URL. This is necessary to prevent a redirect loop, but also means that the URL parameter will take priority over the cookie value, if both are present. This is probably a non-issue and may even be desirable, however, you could potentially validate that the URL parameter (if present) matches the cookie value and replace it if it's different - at the expense of additional complexity.

The second *condition* checks for the `geodefense` cookie and captures its value using the parenthesised subpattern `(\w+)`. This is then available in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string using the `%1` backreference. `\w` is a shorthand character class that denotes *word characters* and is equivalent to the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

---

**UPDATE:**

> is possible to disable this behavior for example on the cart page that would be like this 127.0.0.1/store/cart

You can add an exception - a *negated* condition (`RewriteCond` directive) - before the existing *conditions*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/store/cart
:
```

The above checks that the requested URL-path is not exactly equal to `/store/cart`. The `=` prefix operator makes this an exact match string comparison, rather than a regex. Use a regex if you need more flexibility, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/store/
:
```

The above (regex) checks that the URL-path does not *start with* `/store/`. So naturally excludes `/store/cart` and `/store/<anything>`.

The order of these rules in your `.htaccess` file is important. This rule must go *before* any front-controller pattern you might have, near the top of the `.htaccess` file (but after any blocking directives).

Comment: I appreciate all your explanation very thoroughly.
It is possible to disable this behavior for example on the cart page that would be like this
127.0.0.1/store/cart

Comment: Hello, the code works but only in the home of the site, strangely with example parameters:
https://127.0.0.1.com/store/crop-v2 not working

Comment: Strangely I put the code at the top of my .htaccess and it started working.
Thanks!!

Comment: @EduRafael I've updated my answer to include an exception for the "cart page". Yes, the order of the rules in your `.htaccess` file is important - a rule like this needs to go before the front-controller pattern, near the top of the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thank you very much you deserve heaven! everything works great